# Having issue with modifying data in Firebase realtime database using PATCH

Tags: rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning to implement to write data in Firebase Realtime Database using C compiler. I use  this PATCH to modify value as in below. I requested but the response is having error. May I know how to correct this error?

```
PATCH /.json HTTP/1.1
Host: minmin-68c89.firebaseio.com
Accept: */*
{"dir":"1"}


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2019 12:04:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

{
   "error" : "No data supplied."
                                }
                                 ATCH /.json HTTP/1.1
Host: minmin-68c89.firebaseio.com
Accept: */*
{"dir":"1"}
```

Comment: What's the error, and exact response?

Comment: The front part is the request and the rest are the response

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need an empty line between the headers and the body of the request.

Also consider adding a `content-type` header.

From a quick `curl` test I did:

```
PATCH /users/jack/name/.json HTTP/1.1
Host: PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"last":"Jones"}
```